# Flutter: Peek-pop effect like instagram

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to implement a peek-pop effect as they have on the Instagram profile page. I have tried using `GestureDectector`. I show the dialog using `onLongPressStart` and after that, I am unable to register the `onLongPressEnd` for the dialog to pop out using the Navigator. Can somebody help me on how to implement this feature. 
 [Effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZyws.gif)

Answer (score 0):

`GestureDetector` has `onLongPress` & `onLongPressEnd` methods:

```
GestureDetector(
        onLongPress: () {
          print('long press start');
        },
        onLongPressEnd: (LongPressEndDetails longPressEndDetails) {
          print('long press end');
    // Call Navigator.pop(context); or Navigator.of(context).pop();
        },
    child: Container(child: Text('Click me'),
    )
```

Comment: onLongPressEnd not working when I am putting a showDialog in onLongPress.